Kan complexes and $S$ functor
In our lecture we constructed the functor $S: Top \to sSet$ which sends $X \mapsto \hom_{Top}(\Delta^{\bullet},X)$. We proved that $S(X)$ is always a Kan complex, however I was wondering if also every Kan complex comes from a topological space by this. I tried to prove this but I have no idea how to construct $X$ from a given simplicial set.
Anyone has an idea?

There are Kan complexes with only one $0$-simplex but several $1$-simplexes, e.g. the nerve of any non-trivial group. The first part would mean that $X$ has only one point, which would contradict the second part.
Instead of isomorphism the interesting notion for simplicial sets is typically homotopy equivalence. Any simplicial set has an associated topological space, called its geometric realization, and when we apply your construction to this space, we get a simplicial set homotopy equivalent to the original one (but typically much larger).
Look at the Wikipedia article simplicial set as a first source.
